# Serverless Offline <> React - Local Dev Page Load

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, serverless, serverless-offline

I have a serverless application that is using the `serverless-offline` plugin and `create-react-app` to load a front-end client, but I'm not sure how I can configure my serverless app to load the `index.html` page and also the proper link format that I can use within my react app to call the serverless-offline generated routes.

I know that serverless applications typically use a static website hosted on S3 and AWS serverless endpoints within the static links to trigger the handlers, but I'm not sure how I can replicate this in the local environment. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my code structure at the moment:

```
- frontend (create-react-app)
-- create-react-files
- backend
-- controllers
--- login.js
```

I then have a proxy set up in my `create-react-app` config file set to `serverless-offline` port I configured in my `serverless.yml` file